# unable to extract string between patterns using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

My Input String :"CR 1513II2255651 202OL19010200785 FX:1 NEAT LIMITE mndfgusadg202OL19010200785 NEAT LIMITED NEAT LIMITED HKD 52194.2"

I want to extract anything in between **FX:1** & **the first alphanumeric word**, in this case expected output is : **NEAT LIMITE**

I have tried below code but not getting desired solution

```
var str = "CR 1513II2255651 202OL19010200785 FX:1 NEAT LIMITE mndfgusadg202OL19010200785 NEAT LIMITED NEAT LIMITED HKD 52194.2"

var pattern = "FX:1 (.*) ((?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z]))+"
str.match(pattern);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```js
var str = "CR 1513II2255651 202OL19010200785 FX:1 NEAT LIMITE mndfgusadg202OL19010200785 NEAT LIMITED NEAT LIMITED HKD 52194.2"

var pattern = /FX:1\s+(.*?)\s+(?:[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z])/;
var result = str.match(pattern);
if (result) {
  console.log(result[1]); // Get only Group 1 value
}
```

Pattern details

- `FX:1` - a literal string
- `\s+`  - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars as few as possible
- `\s+`  - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?:[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z])` - either

  - `[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]` - 1+ letters and then a digit
  - `|` - or
  - `[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]` - 1+ digits and then a letter.

See the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=FX%3A1%5Cs%2B(.*%3F)%5Cs%2B(%3F%3A%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B%5B0-9%5D%7C%5B0-9%5D%2B%5Ba-zA-Z%5D)):

[image]